# when i m doing active-active replication using SymmetricDS while registration of port it give me error

Tags: symmetricds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL8jI.png)

anyone knows about it  i got engine unregistered  on SymmetricDS while open registration

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you specified an invalid engine name when running the symadmin command. Make sure that the engine name you specify has a corresponding properties file in SymmetricDS's engines directory.